# Custom Ribbon button in Calendar event edit form SP2013

Tags: ribbon, 2013, custom-actions, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to define a ribbon button that appears in the calendar new event and/or modify event form using Visual Studio.

I am perfectly able to have a ribbon button appear in the list view and other places, but not in the edit form. How do I do this?

[image]

"My button here" is where I want to place my ribbon button.
Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Figured out it's all about Location, Location, Location!

Editing the elements.xml to the following worked:

```
<CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Actions.Controls._children">
   <Button Id="MyButton"
      Alt="My Button"
      Sequence="100"
      Command="Invoke_MyButtonRequest"
      LabelText="My Button"
      TemplateAlias="o1"
      Image32by32="_layouts/15/images/placeholder32x32.png"
      Image16by16="_layouts/15/images/placeholder16x16.png" />
</CommandUIDefinition>
```

Seems like the syntax is the same as in 2010.

Some good resources on the topic here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms473643.aspx

http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/01/customizing-ribbon-part-1-creating-tabs.html